# KML/XML parsing giving error that "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, kml, scrape

So, I'm currently trying to parse specific data in a KML doc that I have, and after I correctly load the doc (checked that it was loaded correctly via debugger), it seems that it won't read into any elements I'm trying to scrape.
I keep receiving the error message of "System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements". Could anyone explain why my code may not work? I've exhausted a lot of documentation and other stack posts to no avail.

```
public async Task ExecuteKMLCrawl()
        {
            var club = new ClubInfo();
            var list = new List<ClubInfo>();
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\downloads\doc.kml");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
            var placemarks =
                (from x in xDoc.Descendants()
                    where x.Name.LocalName == "Placemark"
                    select new XElement(x)).ToList();
            foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
            {
                //club.ClubName = (from x in placemark.Descendants("name") 
                  //  select x).First().Value;

                club.Name = (from x in placemark.Descendants("Data")
                    where x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "President"
                    select x).First().Value;

                club.Email = (from x in placemark.Descendants("Data")
                    where x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "Email"
                    select x).First().Value;

                club.City = (from x in placemark.Descendants("Data")
                    where x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "City"
                    select x).First().Value;

                club.State = (from x in placemark.Descendants("Data")
                    where x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "State"
                    select x).First().Value;

            }
            list.Add(club);
            await _kmlClubs.InsertManyAsync(list);
```

XML/KML code shown below:

```
<Placemark>
        <name>Club Name</name>
        <address>*Address Contained Here*</address>
        <ExtendedData>
          <Data name="President">
            <value>*President Name*</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="Email">
            <value>s*President Email*</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="College/University">
            <value>*College Name*</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="City">
            <value>*City Name*</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="State">
            <value>*State Initials*</value>
          </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>
```

Result of placemark.Descendants("name").ToList();

```
<Placemark xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <name>Mississippi State Swim Club</name>
  <address>Mississippi State University Starkville MS</address>
  <description><![CDATA[President: Private Name<br>Email: Private@gmail.com<br>College/University: Mississippi State University<br>City: Starkville<br>State: MS]]></description>
  <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1</styleUrl>
  <ExtendedData>
    <Data name="President">
      <value>Private Name</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Email">
      <value>private@gmail.com</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="College/University">
      <value>Mississippi State University</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="City">
      <value>Starkville</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="State">
      <value>MS</value>
    </Data>
  </ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Further info, the first line statement the console lists as problematic is where I start club.Name. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result of `placemark.Descendants("name").ToList();` in your question?

Comment: Did you check, in the debugger, to see if `placemark` has any descendants called `Data` with a `name` attribute equal to `“President”`? First() will throw that exception if it doesn’t.

Comment: @Progman I've added what placemark contains in the debugger after running that line, it seems to find "name" alright. This is shown in my edit of my question at the bottom. I believe this is also similar to what you're asking, Ed, as it also seems to pick up presidents in the debugger too. There are a total of 114 clubs, and all of them are stored in placemarks correctly according to debugger. Yet my code just cant seems to find anything within.

Comment: ^^^^@EdPlunkett

Comment: Your code works fine with the XML sample provided. Either there's one or more clubs with no president, or "where I start club.Name" doesn't mean what I think it does, or something else. I'd put a try/catch around the inside of that loop, put a breakpoint in the catch, and look at the exact state of everything when it throws. You may even find it's actually throwing elsewhere.

Comment: @EdPlunkett basically "club.Name" is just storing the value there so it can be added to a list, which that list can be added later to my MongoDB. As you said, I see no reason why it won't work either. I'll add some null checks and see if it'll pass.

Comment: I know what club.Name is doing; that's very clear, I just wasn't entirely sure what you were trying to say with that sentence.